# Object sent -autorelease too many times (iOS5)

Tags: ios, ternary-operator, autorelease

I've struck a problem using the latest XCode beta (4.2 Build 4C114, iOS 5.0) and autorelease that I can't solve. The code needs to conditionally set a string which will be the message in an alert:

```
NSString* msg = ([result rangeOfString:@"Ok"].location == NSNotFound) ?
  @"Upload failed" : @"Uploaded ok";
```

Running Analyze highlights the line saying "Object sent -autorelease too many times (2)".
And sho'nuf, running the app (under the Simulator) causes a SIGABRT double free.

I've tried coding the line as an if/else.
I've tried creating separate strings for the two messages and just assigning the appropriate pointer to a third pointer with the ternary and if/else.
Nothing I do makes this go away!

Comment: You don't need to (auto)release `msg` as you did not allocate or copy it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a string with @"string contents" will always be autoreleased automatically. You don't need to specifically release it yourself.

In most cases you would only need to release an object if you called "alloc" or "new" on it to begin with.

Comment: Technically, a constant string like @"foo" isn't autoreleased. It is more like a global variable. If you call autorelease on it, the autorelease does nothing.